# How to implement modal pop up as window.open() using focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Combining window.open() with focus() I am achieving a window thrown on top of all other windows(if all windows are minimised too). Here is the code :

```
function popitup() {
newwindow=window.open('www.google.com','name','height=200,width=150');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
popitup();
setInterval ( popitup, 10000 );
```

Now I am facing a problem, that I have to do the same for popup window/modal popup which will come on top of all windows opened. Is it possible through javascript? How?

Comment: _`I have to do the same for popup window/modal popup`_... not getting it.

Comment: That the popup will come over all windows opened, or all windows minimised. In a simpler way there is no choice for the user to overlook the popup.